# Обновление сайта из Git-репозитория

Tags: git, хостинг, git-commit, репозиторий, обновление

Есть закрытый (платный) репозиторий на github.com
Есть рабочий сайт. Нужно обновлять код сайта из репозитория.
Сейчас в корневой папке папке сайта лежит клонированный репозиторий (папка .git), обновление происходит через команду:

```
git pull
```

Держать папку .git в корне сайта как-то не безопасно, да и зачем собственно она там вообще нужна, ведь с рабочего сервера (сайта) никаких commit'ов не бывает. Нужно только обновлять файлы в одну сторону из репозитория.

Подскажите есть ли такая возможность обойтись без локального репозитория на хостинге для обновления сайта?

Comment: git hook на стороне репозитория гит

Comment: Что-то я не понял они то тут при чем? Читаю: "Хуки в git это некие скрипты, срабатывающие на определенные события, по сути своей являются их обработчиками. Расположены они в каталоге .git/hooks." -- как это мне может помочь? Это мне какой-то "велосипед обновления удаленного сервера" надо писать чтобы он запускался через hook при очередном коммите в репозиторий у меня на локальной машине?

Comment: самое простое сделать на сервере структуру каталогов:
.git/
wwwroot/
logs/
.gitignore

тогда в корне сайта не будет .git  а вы будете уверены что контент сайта точно соответствует тому что в репозитории, и никакой гнусный хакер не подбросил вам туда свой злоскрипт.

Comment: т.е., держать папку .git (репозиторий) выше корневой папки сайта? Я же правильно понял?